# Floating Pop-up video window in iPhone X

Tags: iphone, ios

On my last Samsung Galaxy phone (which I still use; I believe it’s an S5?), when you’re watching a video that is downloaded onto the phone, there is an option to [shrink the video playback screen](https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobile-devices/how-do-i-watch-a-video-on-samsung-galaxy-s5-while-doing-something-else-on-the-device/) so that it is in the corner of the phone’s screen. From here you are able to watch a smaller version of the video while going about your routine on a fully functional phone. You can also drag the smaller video screen around the phone’s screen to move it to a more convenient area (without stopping play).

Additionally, due to one of the more recent updates to the device, you can now do the same thing while watching a YouTube video - i.e. make the viewing screen small, move it around, and watch it while you do whatever you like on your phone.

I recently got an iPhone X, and it is my first iPhone. Does iPhone have any such feature? If so, how do I employ it?

Comment: As a personal opinion, this is one of the reasons why I don't participate in the Apple ecosystem... If Apple doesn't give you "permission" to do this then there's no way to customize it, no workaround, nothing. You just can't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is called Picture-in-Picture mode in iOS. Currently it is only available in certain iPad models which also run the same version of the software just like your iPhone X.

- [Use Multitasking on your iPad](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207582)

> [image]

As of this writing, this feature is not available in iOS running on iPhone X (or any other iPhone), some 3rd party apps such as WhatsApp and YouTube provide similar feature in a somewhat restricted manner. Major restriction being that the app should continue running in the foreground while you playback the video.

- [WhatsApp for iPhone updated with Picture-in-Picture mode, other improvements](https://www.phonearena.com/news/WhatsApp-iPhone-update-adds-PiP-mode-other-improvements_id104704)

> The new Picture-in-Picture mode supports two services for the moment, Instagram and Facebook, which means that whenever you receive a link to a video hosted by one of these services, you'll be able to play it right within WhatsApp.
>
> Moreover, you'll be able to continue to watch the video while navigating to another chat and share your impressions with your friends. But that's not all that WhatsApp included in the latest update.

[image] [image]

[YouTube's iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/youtube-watch-listen-stream/id544007664) also support picture-in-picture video playback mode while you continue browsing the app. It has the limitation that the shrunk video playback window isn't floating and can't be moved around to a new location on screen.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Picture in Picture on iOS is [only available on iPad](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207582) currently.

> You can use Picture in Picture with iPad Pro, iPad (5th generation and later), iPad Air and later, or iPad mini 2 and later.